# How to Produce the Acute Accent When Using the a Font from the Sqrcaps Package

Tags: fonts, xetex, accents, french, sqrcaps

Consider the code which I compile with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sqrcaps}

% I COMPILE THIS CODE WITH XELATEX:
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\noindent I would like to write, say, \textbf{\'{e}crire l'accent aigu} with the \emph{sqrcfamily} font, but I cannot produce the acute accent at all:
\vspace*{15pt}
\begin{center}
\sqrcfamily{\'{e}crire l'accent aigu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and which produces the output:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I apply "l'accent aigu" to the letter 'e' when using a font from the `sqrcaps` family and when the code is to be compiled with `xelatex`?

Thank you.

Comment: Judging from this specimen sheet (https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/fonts/bookhands/sqrcaps/allsqrcaps.pdf) it looks as though this particular font has no characters other than the regular English A-Z: No umlauts, no accents, nothing.

Comment: That said: Since you are using XeLaTeX anyway, why not get a similar looking font with better character support and just use that, instead of the old LateX package?

Comment: never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xelatex

Comment: Then there will be a question on how to get `ç`, one about `ł` and one about `ř`? The font has NO support whatsoever for accents. I find it ugly (but this is subjective), but if you want to use it in your document you're the judge. Be aware of the font's limitations. By the way, you're still using `fontenc` with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Ingmar I use xelatex for a certain title page that with decorative features that I later call into a document compiled with either `pdflatex` or `lualatex`. I have only been able to compile the said title page with `xelatex`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the comment; and sorry about the `fontenc`---I recall seeing on this site somewhere that it was recommended with the use of the `sqrcfamily` font. It sounds like your admonition is universal against the use of `fontenc` with `xelatex` regardless of the font. I hope to remember that. Thanks again.

Comment: @mlchristians The `sqrcaps` package is essentially independent on the default output encoding as set by `fontenc` or `fontspec`. It just provides the same font for every output encoding.

Comment: you had set T1 for the whole document not just the sqrccaps font so had broken linebreaking everywhere. As that font only has A-Z the encoding you call it is fairly arbitrary,OOT1, T1, TU, it is compatible of, but a subset of, all three of those. and anyway if  as here you use the package-defined command it uses a fixed encoding for the font independent of the current encoding at that point.

Comment: Are you sure you can only typeset the page with xelatex, you have to try quite hard to make a xelatex document that can not be adjusted to work with luatex

Comment: @David Carlisle It's a title page template I use often. I know I cannot compile it with `pdflatex` becaue of certain decorative features I use. And just the other day, I tried doing so with `lualatex` but failed. It seems my only recourse is to keep compiling it with `xelatex` and later inserting it as a page within the document.

Comment: @mlchristians given a choice of spending 5 minutes figuring out why it didn't work with luatex or having to use a two-engine build forever, that isn't clearly a win

Comment: @David Carlisle Are both the `pstricks` and `psvectorian` packages compatible with `lualatex`? I rather thought that that might be the problem---which is the incompatibility issue with `pdflatex`. As for the `lualatex` compilation---that is a most recent one on my part based on your suggestion a week or so ago because of an external font that I needed to use. All of the alluded to documents save one are compiled with `pdflatex`, but it would be nice to compile the title page with `lualatex` if ever needed again. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: pstricks is since Marcel added Lua support last year, psvectorian I don't think I ever used so you'd have to check:-)

Comment: Many thanks @David Carlisle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use T1 encoding (for the main text font) in xelatex.

For the accent you can use any font that has an acute, I use bold Roman here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sqrcaps}

% I COMPILE THIS CODE WITH XELATEX:
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\noindent I would like to write, say, \textbf{\'{e}crire l'accent aigu} with the \emph{sqrcfamily} font, but I cannot produce the acute accent at all:
\vspace*{15pt}
\begin{center}
\sqrcfamily\textrm{\bfseries\'{\normalfont\sqrcfamily e}}crire l'accent aigu
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks @David Carlisle; and for the admonition regarding T1 encoding.